# Dynamic Cell in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am working on dynamic cell in my **tableView** and give it these two function:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

return 100;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

And I pin my label to the top and bottom of the cell.

The conflict is: When I run the code for the first time there is no dynamic cell and give wrong height.

When I'm scrolling down and return it convert to dynamic cell.

I used:`[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:YES];`
in the function: `(nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Can anyone explain what happened to my view?

[image: Image before scrolling]

[image: Image after scrolling]

Comment: I think You are getting table data in ViewDidload method and reloading table view in viewDidLoad. So get the array in separate method and call that method after 0.1 seconds from viewDidLoad and reload it.

Comment: I send a get request. 
When the request come back and handle I call reloadData.
I call it in a separate method.

Comment: Change estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath 100 to UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: You use UITableViewAutomaticDimension when you want to tell the cell the height is not calculated yet, and it should use with heightForRowAtIndexPath. estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath you need to put the estimated height "not correct once" so it will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change estimateHeight number change to bigger number. For exmaple 300.

Comment: estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath you use it to put the estimated height "not correct once" so it will return the same.

Comment: How about reload tableView in viewDidLoad? After init all items redraw tableView again at the last time.

Comment: I used it. and i use function **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** in dequeueReusableCell Before i return cell. But still give me the same result :( .

Comment: How did you use  dequeueReusableCell?? And also try this. Before return your cell, call cell.layoutIfNeeded() in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: - (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UserCell *cell = (UserCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userCell"];
    // define user
    User *user = [[User alloc]init];
    // if there is no data
    if (self.users.count == 0) {
        return cell;
    }

    user = self.users[indexPath.row];
    
    // define new cell of type UserCell
    UserCell *userCell = (UserCell *) cell;
    
    // update cell UI
    [userCell updateUI:user];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: above the function dequeueRuesableCell.
I will try **cell.layoutIfNeeded()**

Comment: Finally it's work :D.

And i didnt use ** layoutIfNeeded** function.

Comment: thanx bro, hope the best to you ;) .

Answer (score 0):

"The conflict is: When I run the code for the first time there is no dynamic cell and give wrong height.

When I'm scrolling down and return it convert to dynamic cell."

--if you want same height on first run and after scrolling the tableview , set the same height value on both delegate functions -> estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath, heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I want it dynamic not a fixed height. Estimated used to give approximate not correctly height.

Comment: dynamic means, set height with respective to text size ?

Comment: yup.
 You need to use it when you have un estimated height. For example, if you have label and you need to assign to its text a value. And this value might be 3 lines or 5 or just one word. you can use dynamic cell in this case. **Dynamic** will give cell height from label height. To achieve this   you need to bind the top and bottom of the **Label** to top and bottom of the **cell** and give **Label numberOfLines = 0**

Comment: have you checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022387/ios-dynamic-height-for-uitableviewcell  ?

Comment: Yup. I do it correctly. But i dont know why it wasn't working. I fixed the problem, the problem is the cell need to reload it after you add content to it.

Comment: Yup, Thanks bro.